# MySQL database sync options

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

What are some of the good options to sync two or more MySQL databases of the same schema, situated at different locations; reliably?

We have four database in four different locations.

we tried using the generic master master replication but the link breaks again and again leading to inconsistencies.

Comment: 1) Have you tried mysql's built-in replication? 2) What does it mean that you could not link all databases? 3) DBAs would be in a lot better position to answer this question than sw developers. Consider migrating the question to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Shadow 1) yes , 2) link between databases breaks again and again 3) okay

Answer (score 1):

[SymmetricDS](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview) can replicate MySQL to MySQL.  There is also a [community edition](http://www.symmetricds.org/)